# selenium parse element - actual code/parser to understand how it works

Tags: selenium, xml-parsing, html-parsing

How does Selenium identify an element - ie how does get the browser and read the html and identify the element ? did they implement some sort of html/xml parsers?

Comment: What is the Selenium in-built parser to identify Html/XMl?

Comment: They're not using parsers they are using javascript to find elements

Comment: do you know how I can read the code ? I have downloaded selenium Source but I am lost - how do I find where do they parse it